# Handling multiple data filter and sort queries with restful services

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, restful-url

I am looking at options to refactor a horrible system and it makes sense to remove a lot of the data concerns and put them in a restful web service. However the one thing that I am not sure about is the way I would filter, sort and page the data. As with restful based queries it is usually broken up over many parts of the route, but what if you need to do very complex queries?

Most examples show typical things like:

`http://some-service.com/customers/UK` Which would get all customers in uk

But what if I wanted to get all customers within the UK with an Age of under 28 sorted by Surname paged from index 0 to 50?

`http://some-service.com/customers/UK/LT28/Surname/0/50/` This *may* do it but then the first parameter is always expecting to be a country, then somehow must turn LT28 into the logical `< 28` then know that the 3rd parameter is a sort and then paging. It just all seems very brittle and static, so lets say you are happy with the above, how do you do the query where you want all customers who have not been billed, pages from index 0 to 50?

`http://some-service.com/customers/NotBilled/0/50/` This *may* do it but hopefully you will see the point im trying to get at here by now.

So is there a best practice way to handle this sort of problem within restful services?

I am specifically working within a .net environment at the moment but didnt want to constrain the answer by technology, as hopefully if there is a good way to solve this problem then most frameworks will support it.

Comment: If we're talking about the same thing, complex queries are not a big problem for c# and restful webservice http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/more-complex-rest-requests.html Let's take this example http://www.acme.com/phonebook/UserDetails?firstName=John&lastName=Doe
we've got UserDetails object and its firstName, lastName fields. As far as I know, c# will bind values passed in query automagically to proper fields in the object. //EDIT: Unfortunatelly this answer is very constrained by technology :)

Comment: Oh I assumed there would be some `best practice` for doing this and each framework would support that given pattern in its own way. I dont mind constraining to C# if it will give a better quality answer for this problem. I was surprised that the query string is used, as I was udner the impression that the query string was not conducive to good restful routes, however I was struggling to see a way to do a GET based query without it :)